# Crosses in Gluing Patterns on Fundamental Domains

Tags: general-topology, geometry, surfaces

I am trying to work through Mostly Surfaces by Schwarz, but his explanations can be quite confusing. I am working on the section about the Euler Characteristic of surfaces. For instance he writes

> It remains to consider the case when there is just one face whose boundary edges are paired in some way. We call this a gluing pattern for Σg. We say that the gluing pattern has a cross if we can find two
>   pairs of glued edges (e1,e2) and (f1,f2) such that any line segment connecting e1 to e2 crosses any line segment connecting f1 to f2, as shown in Figure 3.4. In other words, the edges e1,e2 separate the edges f1,f2 from each other on the boundary of P.

[image]

Isn't this a picture showing that the two lines don't cross? I'm clearly not understanding something.

Comment: Your picture does not depict any line segment connecting $e_1$ to $e_2$, nor any line segment connecting $f_1$ to $f_2$. If you draw such line segments, the quote will make a lot more sense.

Comment: Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are identified, can't the line segment from $e_1$ to $e_2$ be drawn as a line from $e_1$ into $f_1$, out of $f_2$ and into $e_2$?

Comment: I think it's to be interpreted *before* the gluing.

Comment: The comment of @Berci is right. The gluing diagram, before gluing, is a convex polygon in the plane. The line segments are straight line segments in the plane.